# Remove number under barcode and write text in python 3

Tags: python, image, image-processing, label, barcode

I was trying to generate some bar-code (using [python-barcode](https://pypi.org/project/python-barcode/)) with product info I successfully generate bar-code but Not to remove under code and write my own text

**My code:**

```
import barcode
from barcode.writer import ImageWriter

barCode = "00000016901011900000"
barCodeImage = barcode.get('Code128', barCode, writer=ImageWriter())
barCodeImage.save("one")
```

Which gives me this barcode

[image]

But **I want to remove that showing number under the bar-code and write some text** (*as product info or name*)

Comment: [Create your own writer](https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/python-barcode/blob/master/docs/writers/create_writer.rst) and override `.paint_text()` method.

Comment: would you please give me an example @Selcuk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a method using OpenCV

- Convert image to grayscale
- Otsu's threshold to obtain binary image
- Dilate to connect contour
- Find contours and filter using contour area
- Replace ROI with desired text

---

After converting to grayscale, we Otsu's threshold to get a binary image

[image]

Now we dilate to connect the contours

[image]

From here we find contours and sort using contour area. The smaller contour will be the ROI of the number. Here's the detected number ROI

[image]

Now we "erase" the number by coloring in the ROI with white and write our desired text with `cv2.putText()`. Here's the result

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
dilate = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=3)

cnts = cv2.findContours(dilate, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)

for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    image[y:y+h, x:x+w] = [255,255,255]
    cv2.putText(image, 'Super Spicy Example Text', (x,y), \
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .6, (0,0,0), 1)
    break

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
barCodeImage.save("one", text="Put your text here")
```

You can also use this with the writer:

```
barCodeImage.write(buffer, text="Put your text here")
```

Source: https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/python-barcode/blob/722d45eb3f3fe01da23155ddb0856ee0916cddf4/barcode/base.py#L56

Comment: please add more explanation for others to understand your answer better